# bearer token working on swagger but not working on postman after login on postman

Tags: postman, nestjs, swagger, backend

When I hit the login API in postman, It works after I hit the other API with bearer token got after login is showing invalid or expired token but the same API when i hit with the same bearer token in swagger it showing results. this happens almost all the API that required bearer token in postman only.

I want to know why my postman is invalid token to valid token.

[image: API tested on postman after getting access token]

[image: same access token used to test API on swagger and it works]

Comment: If you have access to the API, you can log the token in the terminal and compare what you're receiving from both ends.

Answer (score 1):

`Bearer token` as an option on postman usually means the token is sent in the `Authorization` headed with the scheme `Bearer <token>`. Looking at your swagger screenshot, it looks like you want to send the token as the `Bearer` header instead, which I don't believe postman has built in/automated support for, so you'll need to set that header yourself